# dynamic_reconfigure and catkin

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I would like to know if there is a way, even a workaround, of generating dynamic_reconfigure files from a catkin package. AFAIK, there is no way currently to use dynamic_reconfigure in a catkin package as the CMake macro is not compatible (rely on rosbuild macros).

1. Is there a workaround?
2. Is it planned for dynamic_reconfigure to switch to catkin?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51634/dynamic_reconfigure-and-catkin/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe there is a way do generate the files using catkin:

In your CMakeLists.txt

> #add dynamic reconfigure api
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED dynamic_reconfigure)
> generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(relative_path_to_file1 relative_path_to_file2 ...)

From the dynamic reconfigure tutorial: http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile

---

Originally posted by [adobke](https://answers.ros.org/users/3920/adobke/) with karma: 71 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-01-08**:
Ok, I overlooked this page, this is what I am looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Examples of catkin packages using dynamic_reconfigure are image_rotate or stereo_image_proc:
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/tree/master/stereo_image_proc

It is possible that the documentation is not yet up-to-date for this, if you find it lacking, create a ticket on dynamic_reconfigure.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-01-08**:
Apparently it was not lacking, just not so obvious to find. Hope this question will makes information easier to get ;)